# Sql sorting wrong

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sorting

Why does my sorting not work as it should? If i click to sort the value of my select under then it only sorts after the first number so if i have values like 100,33,2100,4432 then i get this order 100,2100,33,4432

How can 100 be smaller then 33 and so on...

```
SELECT Replace(
      CONVERT(VARCHAR, 
         CONVERT(INTEGER, Sum( 
           Isnull( 
           a.planabsatz_mt1 + a.planabsatz_mt2 
                 + a.planabsatz_mt3 + a.planabsatz_mt4 
                 + a.planabsatz_mt5 + a.planabsatz_mt6 
                 + a.planabsatz_mt7 + a.planabsatz_mt8 
                 + a.planabsatz_mt9 + a.planabsatz_mt10 
                 + a.planabsatz_mt11 + a.planabsatz_mt12, 0))), 1), 
          '.00', '')
```

Comment: This sounds like what is called a lexical sort, and occurs when you sort a text field containing a number.

Comment: If strings are compared they will be compared from left to right, character for character. 1 is smaller than 3, finished.

Answer (score 5):

You've converted your values to strings in the select statement you posted.

So, doing an alpha sort, 100 does come before 33.

Answer (score 1):

You're converting the number to a `varchar` before sorting.  Try this:

```
SELECT Replace(
   CONVERT(INTEGER, Sum( 
     Isnull( 
     a.planabsatz_mt1 + a.planabsatz_mt2 
           + a.planabsatz_mt3 + a.planabsatz_mt4 
           + a.planabsatz_mt5 + a.planabsatz_mt6 
           + a.planabsatz_mt7 + a.planabsatz_mt8 
           + a.planabsatz_mt9 + a.planabsatz_mt10 
           + a.planabsatz_mt11 + a.planabsatz_mt12, 0))), 
    '.00', '')
```

Comment: I tried that but it gives the same answer. I Name the column Total = ((Select and so on...After that i make a Order By on Total

Comment: Hmm, I just realised... The REPLACE probably casts to string. Try removing the REPLACE and let me know?